# NullPointerException while getting Font of pagenode using pdfBox

Tags: pdfbox

I am trying to run the following code :

```
for(Object pn : kidList){
        if(pn instanceof PDPageNode)
            {

              PDPageNode pnode =(PDPageNode) pn;
                     PDResources pres = pnode.getResources();
                    Map<String,PDFont>  pfont = pres.getFonts();  
                  //For this NullPointerException is thrown
                    System.out.println("PageNode");
            }
            else
            {
            PDPage pg=(PDPage)pn;
                    PDResources pres = pnode.getResources();
                    Map<String,PDFont>  pfont = pres.getFonts();
                    // No exception here
                    System.out.println("Page");

            }
        }
```

for the pageNode part , I am getting an exception

```
    Map<String,PDFont>  pfont = pres.getFonts();  
                  //For this NullPointerException is thrown
```

However for PDPage , no exception is thrown , and am able to get the font map.
I am not getting why is there an exception for PDPageNode when getting it's font , while there is none in extracting font from the kid page from it.

Comment: Check whether pres is null first. A page node does not need to have resources.

Comment: Yeah , checked it pres is null , however It is not clear to me why pagenode doesn't have resources, as in a page tree ? if you can explain in some way .

Comment: I have this doubt as when I take the map of all pages from document catalog , I am able to elicit resources from each page , so pagenode should also have it

Comment: An **Resources** entry is mandatory only for the individual page nodes, not inner nodes of the **Pages** tree.